# PlotStyle in ListPlot: change color scheme, manually choose color of first plot

Tags: plotting, color

Say i have this data:

```
data1 = Map[Cos, Range[0, 20]];
data2 = Map[Sin, Range[0, 20]];
```

And i want to plot `data1` in gray and a chosen set (with `Manipulate`) of multiplicities of `data2` in several other colors. This code does what I mean:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{data1, Sequence @@ Table[data2*i, {i, k}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {LightGray, 
    Sequence @@ ConstantArray[Automatic, Length[k]]}], {{k, {1, 
    2}}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

I managed to make it work to only plot `data1` in gray and the multiplicities of `data2` in automatic colors, but now I'm stuck at the standard color scheme, although `PlotStyle` accepts `ColorData`. For example:

```
PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]
```

However I don't know how to implement this with the condition that the first plot should be gray.

**Question: Is there a way to change the color scheme in `ListPlot` AND manually choose the color of the first plot?**

Comment: It is because of iterator, it seems to work: `PlotStyle -> {Gray, Sequence @@ Table[Hue[i/10], {i, k }]}`

Comment: I think I don't fully understand what you mean. Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Maybe I missed the point but I thought You have problem with creating list for `PlotStyle`, with dynamic length, starting from Gray.

Comment: Then I probably haven't made myself clear enough... Rold Lm's solution was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
data1 = Map[Cos, Range[0, 20]];
data2 = Map[Sin, Range[0, 20]];    
Manipulate[
  G1 = ListLinePlot[data1, PlotStyle -> {Thick, c0}, 
    PlotRange -> {-4, 4}];
  G2 = ListLinePlot[Table[data2*i, {i, k}], PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x1, x2}, ColorData[c1][x2]]];
  Show[G2, G1],
  {{k, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar},
  {c0, Gray, ColorSlider},
  {c1, ColorData["Gradients"], PopupMenu}]
```

Result:

[image]

You can also try this if you want to manually choose every color:

```
data1 = Map[Cos, Range[0, 20]];
data2 = Map[Sin, Range[0, 20]];
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[{data1, Sequence @@ Table[data2*i, {i, k}]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{c0, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[Automatic, Length[k]]}, c1, c2, c3, c4}], 
  {{k, {1, 2}}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar},
  {c0, Gray, ColorSlider},
  {c1, Red, ColorSlider},
  {c2, Green, ColorSlider},
  {c3, Blue, ColorSlider},
  {c4, Yellow, ColorSlider}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Clever solution! Thanks!