# Controlling ListPlot Line Colors

Tags: plotting

I am using `ListPlot` to display from 5 to 12 lines of busy data. The individual time series in my data are not easy to distinguish visually, as may be evident below, because the colors are not sufficiently different.

[image]

I have been trying to use `PlotStyle`, `ColorData`and related functions to get better colors. I would rather not have to specify a specific list of colors because the number of plot items varies from test to test. I created a toy plot to experiment with - the problem is illustrated by lines "F" and "G", which seem to be almost the same color. `PlotStyle` -> `ColorData` doesn't seem to work.  Is there a simple way to do this?

```
ListPlot[Table[i*Range[0, 10], {i, 1, 5, 0.5}]
 , Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All
 , PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Characters["ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOP"]]
 , PlotStyle -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"]  ]
```

[image]

It looks like

```
ListLinePlot[Table[data2*i, {i, k}], PlotStyle -> Thick, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x1, x2}, ColorData[c1][x2]]]
```

from another [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27131/plotstyle-in-listplot-change-color-scheme-manually-choose-color-of-first-plot?rq=1) may be the answer. I didn't see that before. I'll try it out. I don't think I really understand `ColorData`. Meanwhile, if anyone has generally enlightening comments, I would appreciate them.

Comment: F and G seem to have quite distinguishable colors. I believe B and F are much closer to each other to the extent that I can't distinguish them easily.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Your are right; they are almost identical.

Comment: Pick a long list of colors you like, at least as long as the highest number of plots you want, and use `PlotStyle -> colors`.  Extra colors will be unused.

Comment: Are you aware of the "Color Schemes" palette? Unter "Indexed" you´ll find several discrete `ColorData[n]` templates - perhaps there already is one more to your liking.

Comment: http://phrogz.net/css/distinct-colors.html lets you generate random, perceptually distinct colors according to parameters you can control.  If the main objective is 12 visually distinct colors, then it's more a question of graphic design, not *Mathematica*.  If you have access to V10 (on RPi, say), the default plot colors are perceptually more distinct, but there are only 10 of them (as I recall).

Comment: Is there some reason why this doesn;t suffice? `ListPlot[Table[i*Range[0, 10], {i, 1, 5, 0.5}], Frame -> True, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'm not sure I tried your suggestion. I somehow turned ColorData into a more complicated function than it is, and then tried a lot of things that couldn't actually work.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Large color set for coloring of many datasets on a plot](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/large-color-set-for-coloring-of-many-datasets-on-a-plot)."

Comment: How about a way to do it for those of us who are colorblind and can't distinguish between these colors and would actually like to be able to manually specify colors we can distinguish? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Sarah, you should probably [ask a new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), but briefly: you can always use `PlotStyle` in `ListPlot[]` to specify custom colors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned by others, you should read up on `ColorDataFunctions`. For example, you could evenly space colors across a continuous color scheme, for an arbitrary number of lines, with:

```
d = Table[i*Range[0, 10], {i, 1, 5, 0.5}];
ListPlot[d, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Characters["ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOP"]], 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ (Range[0, Length@d]/Length@d)]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried everything but the right thing with `ColorData`. It turns out this was a easy problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The key is to use one of the *indexed* color sets. You can find them in the color schemes palette or generate them using `ColorData[c]`. The j-th color in scheme i can be obtained using `ColorData[i][j]`.

To generate a set of colors for use in `PlotStyle` you can use

```
PlotStyle->ColorData[2]/@Range[8].
```

Most color schemes only have a finite set of colors to choose from, except scheme 1 and 63. Scheme 1 happens to be the default color scheme.

The following code shows the color schemes as colored spheres in RGB space.

```
Partition[
  Table[
    Graphics3D[{#, 
       Sphere[{##}, 1/10]& @@ #}& /@ (ColorData[c]/@Range[50]/. GrayLevel[g_]->RGBColor[g, g, g]), 
       Lighting -> "Neutral", 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 1/10, 
       PlotLabel -> c, ViewPoint -> {10, 5, 7}
    ], 
    {c, 1, 93}
  ], 
  6, 6, {1, 1}, {}] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can choose a standard scheme or use your own colors, specifying the RGB values manually using `RGBColor` or `Hue`.

Comment: Woo Hoo! A thing of beauty. Thanks.

Comment: This is a really nice way to look at these schemes

Comment: @mfvonh Perhaps a color conversion to CIELab space using `ColorConvert` would be even better. In that way it's easier to see whether the color scheme has a good, perceptually distinguishable set of colors.

Comment: hmm... this makes me think that somebody must have put some thought into the design of these different numbered schemes. For example, scheme, say, 88, should be specifically valuable to illustrate... what exactly?

Comment: @thomas They look better when shown in the designed linear order instead of in RGB space. The name (in the palette's tooltip) may give a hint about its intended use.

Answer (score 3):

I just use `"ColorList"`

```
ListPlot[Table[i*Range[0, 10], {i, 1, 5, 0.5}], Frame -> True, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"]]
```

[image]

You can add some interactivity and choose between the 60+ colour data numbers until you find your preferred set.

From the docs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case all else fails :) ...

```
n = 8;
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[d,
  Frame -> True,
  Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Characters["ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOP"]],
  PlotStyle -> cs],
 {{cs, Array[RGBColor[0.`, 0.`, 0.`] &, n]}, ControlType -> None},
 Column[Outer[Legended[ColorSlider[Dynamic[cs[[#1]]],  AppearanceElements -> "Swatch"], #1]&,
              Range[n]]],
 Initialization -> (d = Table[i*Range[0, 10], {i, 1, n}]), 
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]